# My background plane disappear when I use game engine

Tags: game-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

**This is my blender project before game engine**
[image: This is my blender project before game engine]

**This is the blender engine result as you can se the plane disappear** 
[image]

this only happens when I use the game engine I can render without proble ms

How I can fix that?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the plane was upside down :)